# Would asking on how to utilize a UX feature be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am using (not designing) a program that have a specific UX feature. I want to ask how to utilize this feature. Would it be on-topic here?

I have a number of practices to use it, and am looking for critiques or recommendations. The topic here is *practices to use it*, not *methods to design it*, as in the question [Should critique requests be allowed on the site?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/52226). The question [Should tool-related questions be on-topic?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1179/52226) is only to UX related tools. This tool isn't about designing UX.

The tag [usability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability) seems to be the most fitted tag of my question. Its description says:

> The extent to which a product can be used by specified users to achieve specified goals with effectiveness, efficiency, and satisfaction in a specified context of use.

Any tool is for improving productivity. Therefore it *might* be on-topic on Productivity SE. However, even if it's on-topic, I think it's likely to have more expert answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a definite answer without knowing the question, but it sounds like if you're asking for different options on what do do with a feature, then no, it probably wouldn't work here. That'd be too broad as you'd get people suggesting "you could use it for X" and "Why not use it for Y" with no way to mark any particular answer as the 'correct' one. It'd just be a poll with people voting for the thing they like the best, not people voting for the solution that solves the problem the best.

From the [what to avoid asking](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section of the help centre:

> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

So I would say it probably isn't really going to be an ideal fit for this site.

Comment: How about if I frame it as "how to achieve X (best) with this UX"?

Comment: @Again, it depends on the question itself. But provided it's an answerable question that's not too broad and subjective, and is directly related to UX then sure.